# Type datetime in EditText widget

Tags: android, datetime, android-edittext

I am trying to program EditText to accept datetime value. User would type just numbers and "/" and ":" will be appended automagicaly. Please advice!

I was testing this with InputType and InputFilter. No success.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible to do by using of TextWather and add reqared symbols into requared position.

```
testEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }
```

```
 @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                }
```

```
@Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                Log.e("b", "" + s);
                if (s.length()  2) {
                    s.append('/');
                } else if (s.length()  5) {
                    s.append('/');
                }                 
            }
        });
```

But its rather difficult to understand what user means. For example when he presses "1" buttom in month position, it can be first month or one of "1*" monthes. So should we add point to the end or not?

Comment: This could be a way to go. For numbers must be fixed size. So for first month will type 01. User could type in "/" or ":", but should be ignored. Ie. for **3/11/2013 10:02:00** would type in **03112013100200**